# Access data in .realm file from Python

Tags: python, realm

**Purpose:**

I want to create a web page within a django app where support staff can upload a .realm file and have the web application pull the user and figure out what information in the .realm is missing on the site.

**Question:**

Is there a way to open, read and/or manipulate .realm files with Python? If not, what are my options for converting it to something else like SQLite? Would I need to create some way for the support staff to convert the file before they upload it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to open, read and/or manipulate .realm files with python?

Realm does not currently have a Python SDK.

> If not what are my options for converting it to something else like a sqlite?

To access data from a Realm file on the server side of a web application, your best bet at the present point of time would be to use [Realm's Node.js SDK](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/). Alternatively, you could use a client-side app using one of Realm's other SDKs (Objective-C, Swift, Android, .NET, etc.) to extract the data in question and covert it to a format that your web application can consume.

Comment: Well one of the downside of using realms I guess. I was hoping it wouldn't be as complicated as running a different node.js server or the like, but I'm sure there is a way I can create a stand alone application and convert it to sqlite or something. I've accepted your answer thank you for the response